# How to chain .where for firebase query

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire2

My app allowed user to define backend fields (multiple), then using the 'rules' to chain them (by looping them) to return relevant docs inside a collection.

```
 let eeRef = this.afStore.collection<any>(`.../Collections/EmpSnapshot`).ref
 let eeDoc: any = null
 if (u.bAccessAll) {
     eeDoc = eeRef
 } else {
    for (let r of u.rules) {
        eeDoc = eeRef.where(r.field, r.condition, r.value)
    }
 }

await eeDoc.get()
.then(res => {
    for (let ee of res.docs) {
        emails.push(ee.id)
    }
}).catch(err => {
    console.log(`Error query-ing 'EmpSnapshot': `, err)
})
```

But in the actual fact, the eeDoc variable only can recognize the LAST criteria in the loop and not to chain all criteria up. Example if my rules are

- Fulltime (Staff)
- Finance (Department)
  [image]

I am expecting it to return *all Finance Staff who are Fulltimer*, but my code will only return *'Finance' Staff*
How to fix my code to chain the .where criteria?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're overwriting the `eeDoc` in every iteration of the loop.

This should be closer to what you want:

```
 let eeDoc: any = eeRef

 if (u1.bAccessAll) {
    for (let r of u.rules) {
        eeDoc = eeDoc.where(r.field, r.condition, r.value)
    }
 }
```